# Google Analytics appending index.cfm to end of my URLs

Tags: google-analytics

For some reason Google Analytics is appending index.cfm to the end of all of my URLs when I look at them in GA.  The domain used to be ColdFusion based, but is now a WordPress PHP website running on an Apache server without ColdFusion installed.

We've added new pages to the website, and GA is still reporting an index.cfm at the end of the URL, even though that page never existed on the old ColdFusion site.

I didn't set up the GA account initially, is there maybe a setting that was enabled?  Or does it take GA a while to figure out it's not a ColdFusion website anymore?

By the way, the website in question is http://www.westgatereservations.com.  Thanks.

**--ADDED--**

Screenshot of page list from Google Analytics.  All of these pages are WordPress PHP pages that use a clean permalink URL structure.

[image: Screenshot of Google Analytics Pages for site]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is Google Analytics's 'Default Page' feature. If you go to the Account Settings and Edit the Profile Information, you'll see there's a field called "Default Page". It basically does what the theoretical filter I described above does: it automatically appends the default page (in this case, index.cfm) onto every page URL that doesn't have a page suffix. It's a shortcut, since most of the time, users want /foo and /foo/index.html to be counted as the same thing. But it totally breaks on WordPress and 'prettified' URLs, since they don't have a file suffix.

Just remove the Default Page (leave it blank) and the problem should be resolved. I'm not sure if it will be retroactive (Google Analytics rarely allows retroactive changes), but it will resolve the problem moving forward.

[Read more about Google Analytics Default Page](https://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=32995&hl=en_US)

Comment: There are 2 filters set up on the account, but neither deal with this functionality.  On a sidenote, I had a separate PHP website, that I converted to WordPress, and GA appends index.php to all of the permalinks.  I have a 3rd website that started as a WordPress site, and it doesn't append anything to the permalinks.  It really seems like GA interprets your website's default file extension, and then appends that to the URL.  Almost like it is built into my account or something.  If you start off with clean URLs, then it never appends anything.

Comment: It's very unlikely that this is a built-in feature. I would look closer at the filters to be sure. The only *other* potential explanation is that your Google Analytics snippet has been manually modified in the JavaScript, and that modified script was ported to the new site without changing that. Can you post a link to the page in question, or at least post the Google Analytics snippet you're using?

Comment: I don't think it's a filter issue also because it is also happening on a different site that is linked to a different GA account that contains no filters.  Except on that site it is appending index.php.  I've added a screenshot to my listing above per your request.  Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Took a look at your implementation. It's totally clean. The data is being sent to Google Analytics without the index.cfm, so anything that's causing this has to be on the Google Analytics side, and that could only be in profile configurations. Bizarre.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew this had to be a setting somewhere, but I was looking in the wrong spots.  Thanks again :)

Comment: I just solved the exact issue. My website is at www.brixwork.com/realtors - I intend to expand BRIXWORK to more than realtors, so I set up the domain that way. I figurd, default domain being set to realtors/ for now would be a clever way to determine it. However for ALL WORDPRESS LINKS the Google Analytics side was auto-appending /realtors at the end, messing up my results. Didn't mean traffic didn't flow - it still came through no problem since my URLs were correct on all my Facebook sharing, Mailchimp campaigns etc. Thanks for figureing this out.